# Default Image appear if image removed in Rackspace Cloudfiles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rackspace-cloud

Wild question, but I need/want the ability to have a replacement image appear, using the same url to a cloudfiles image, incase that actual image can't be found.

So in an img tag on someone's blog it would point to an image i host.  if the actual image isn't there anymore, instead of showing that annoying bordered img file that browser's do, i'd like to show another image.

In rails using paperclip, we can set a default image, but that is only if the field isn't populated yet.  It's this thinking i'd like to replicate in real thug life.

thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I made a function similar to this for private branding. The user can upload their own logo to replace my website's logo. Whenever they go to website.com/theircompany it will show their logo and login information. I have it displaying their image instead of the server default by a simple If Then in the view. I look to see if that 'company' has an image uploaded. If it does then display their image. If it does not then display the server default.

UPDATE: Based on your comment below, I see where that can be an issue. If these images will be rather small (<1MB) could you store them in a database? That is how I'm currently handling the images on my server and it sounds like that could work for you. There is a modified Paperclip gem that will allow this. I have forked it since I know that this version works perfectly with my server and MySQL.

https://github.com/kobaltz/paperclip

Comment: my thing is that my users get a link in their image tag of their html on their own blog.  However, the shop that puts the image there, can change the name of that image or delete it... which leaves nothing when the request comes in.  So there isn't anything for me to check, just serve. maybe the default will work, i just have to think of it differently. i'll try it out.

Comment: Ah. that could be an issue. Check my answer for an updated response.

Comment: yeah, but i'm using rackspace cloudfiles for the cdn.  I currently serve them from my own server. thanks though.